# How to remove dupes and replace column variables

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working with a data set named CCCrn on candidates in a local election with some duplicate values. Here's a sample:

```
Adam Hill         4100 New Texas Rd.            Pittsburgh 15239 School Director   PLUM       Democratic     4          5

Adam Hill         4100 New Texas Rd.            Pittsburgh 15239 School Director   PLUM       Republican     4          5
```

As you can see, this candidate cross listed and was on both parties' ballots. I'd like to remove one of the rows, and then edit the Party variable to say "Cross Listed.

Obviously unique and distinct haven't been much help. I tried 
`test <- CCCrn[!duplicated(CCCrn$Name), ]` which succeeded in removing the duplicate canidates, but now I'm not sure how I would go back and edit the "Party" variable.

Comment: `!duplicated(CCCrn)` gets all not duplicated rows.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, none of the rows are perfect dupes, otherwise they'd be much easier to remove :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a flag for duplicate record

```
df <- df %>% mutate(dup = ifelse(duplicated(name)|duplicated(name, fromLast=TRUE),1,0))
df <- df[!duplicated(df$name),]   ## remove duplicate

df <- df %>% mutate(party= ifelse(dup==1, "Cross Listed", party)) # update party

df <- df%>% select(-dup)  ## remove flag
```

Comment: This did the trick! I hadn't thought of using a flag. This is the simplest solution to the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way, using `dplyr`, would be to `group_by` all fields other than the party, and then `summarise` to "CrossListed" if the number of rows in the group is bigger than 1, i.e. if `n()>1`.

Something like this...

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(-Party) %>%
      summarise(Party = ifelse(n() > 1, "CrossListed", first(Party))
```

or an alternative to the last line would be to paste all the party names together so that you can see where they are cross-listed (which might be useful if there are lots of parties - less so if there are only two!)... `summarise(Party = paste(sort(Party), collapse=", "))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the code to work for me. Every time I hit enter, I kept getting the "+" that indicates R is waiting for more code.